# Converting Trent Richardson's DateTime Picker output to Rails-friendly format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date-format, datetimepicker, form-helpers

I'm having trouble getting Trent Richardson's DateTime picker to format output in a way that Rails can understand and properly save to the database.

The following is my model:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :message, :booking_time,  :restaurant_id 

  belongs_to :restaurant

  validates :booking_time, :presence => true
  validates :email, :presence => true
end
```

The following is in my application.js file:

```
$(function () {
    $( "#bookingTime" ).datetimepicker({
      timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
        stepMinute: 5,
        hourMin: 8,
        hourMax: 22
    });
});
```

The following is my _form.html.erb file:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :booking_time, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :booking_time, :id => 'bookingTime', :"data-required" => "true",     :class => "required", :"required" => "true" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm new to Rails and can't determine how to format the time and date in a way that Rails can properly save to the database.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: did you ever figure this out? Im having the same issue